# Looking for average BGR values for each column in each color

Tags: python, numpy, graph, colors, average

We are working on a code that looks at a 96-well plate. We have the centers coordinates of each well. We then created a for loop that would allow us get the BGR value of each well. However, we need to somehow organize each column and average those values. I believe that we are getting an error from the first loop. With this one, it seems like the function only goes through the first loop and not the second one. When I run it, I get 3 values (assuming to be bgr values) and then proceeds to push out the averages. It also seems to repeat some average values. Any suggestions to what I can change, or errors at first-look. I will provide the image and legend below.

Links to images are: 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/CPu28.jpg (the image was scaled, so the coordinates may not work with the uploaded image)
https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kw2JB.jpg

```
import cv2, numpy as np, sys

#filename will be taken from the command line and process as the image variable
#filename= sys.argv([1])
img = cv2.imread('greenandblueplate.jpg')

#centroids
wells = [img[110,97], img[184,97], img[254,97], img[324,97], img[396,96], img[466,97], #columnH 12-7
         img[537,96], img[607,97], img[680,96], img[750,97], img[820,96], img[891,97], #columnH 6-1
         img[110,165],img[184,165],img[254,165],img[324,165],img[396,165],img[466,165], #columnG 12-7
         img[537,165],img[607,165],img[680,165],img[750,166],img[820,165],img[891,165], #columnG 6-1
         img[110,235],img[184,235],img[254,235],img[324,235],img[396,235],img[466,235], #columnF 12-7
         img[537,235],img[607,235],img[680,235],img[750,235],img[820,235],img[891,235], #columnF 6-1
         img[110,305],img[184,305],img[254,305],img[324,305],img[396,305],img[466,305], #columnE 12-7
         img[537,305],img[607,305],img[680,305],img[750,305],img[820,305],img[891,305], #columnE 6-1
         img[110,373],img[184,373],img[254,373],img[324,373],img[396,373],img[466,373], #columnD 12-7
         img[537,373],img[607,373],img[680,373],img[750,372],img[820,373],img[891,373], #columnD 6-1
         img[110,442],img[184,442],img[254,442],img[324,442],img[396,442],img[466,442], #columnC 12-7
         img[537,442],img[607,442],img[680,442],img[750,443],img[820,442],img[891,442], #columnC 6-1
         img[109,511],img[184,511],img[254,511],img[324,511],img[396,511],img[466,511], #columnB 12-7
         img[537,512],img[607,512],img[680,511],img[750,511],img[820,511],img[891,511], #columnB 6-1
         img[109,582],img[184,582],img[254,582],img[324,581],img[396,582],img[466,582], #columnA 12-7
         img[537,581],img[607,582],img[680,582],img[750,581],img[820,582],img[891,582]] #columnA 6-1

bAvgFilledWells = []
gAvgFilledWells = []
rAvgFilledWells = []

#filtering out the centroids that are not needed
#and getting the bgr values for the first color on the plate
for center in wells:
    if center[1] > 124:
        if center[0] < 360:
            b = img[center[0]-4: center[0]+5, center[1]-4: center[1]+5, 0]
            g = img[center[0]-4: center[0]+5, center[1]-4: center[1]+5, 1]
            r = img[center[0]-4: center[0]+5, center[1]-4: center[1]+5, 2]
            bAvg = np.mean(b)
            gAvg = np.mean(g)
            rAvg = np.mean(r)

            bAvgFilledWells.append(bAvg)
            gAvgFilledWells.append(gAvg)
            rAvgFilledWells.append(rAvg)
            print(center)
            print("For the first color, average value for blue is:", bAvg)
            print("For the first color, average value for green is:", gAvg)
            print("For the first color, average value for red is:", rAvg)


bAvgFilledWells2 = []
gAvgFilledWells2 = []
rAvgFilledWells2 = []

#filtering out the centroids that are not needed
#and getting the bgr values for the second color on the plate        
for center in wells:
    if center[1] > 124:
        if center[0] > 360 and center[0] < 642:
            b2 = img[center[0]-4: center[0]+5, center[1]-4: center[1]+5, 0]
            g2 = img[center[0]-4: center[0]+5, center[1]-4: center[1]+5, 1]
            r2 = img[center[0]-4: center[0]+5, center[1]-4: center[1]+5, 2]
            bAvg2 = np.mean(b2)
            gAvg2 = np.mean(g2)
            rAvg2 = np.mean(r2)

            print(center)
            print("For the second color, average value for blue is:", bAvg2)
            print("For the second color, average value for green is:", gAvg2)
            print("For the second color, average value for blue is:", rAvg2)
            bAvgFilledWells2.append(bAvg2)
            gAvgFilledWells2.append(gAvg2)
            rAvgFilledWells2.append(rAvg2)
```

Comment: This looks strangely familiar :) By the way you have a typo in the 4th-from-last line, blue should be red.

Comment: I still can't clearly understand what is wrong. Can you give an example of "seems to repeat some average values"? If the second loop is not producing any output, you could insert some debugging print statements at the top of the loop and after each `if` statement.

Comment: Image of what was ran: http://imgur.com/KExYXJy ....As I go through all the information, the second loop for BGR averages for second color was not shown. After I figure this out, I need to somehow get the average values of each well in a column and average them together.

Comment: It's better to copy and paste text as text rather than screenshots or photos, but I think I have understood what is going on. Posting an answer ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The huge array `wells` at the beginning looks cumbersome and repetitive. It could be improved by creating lists of the X/Y positions of columns A-H and rows 1-12.

And this is the source of your errors: in the loops, you're parsing `center` as if it is the x,y position, but in fact it is the pixel retrieved from `img`.

Instead something like:

```
columns = [110,124,160] # give 8 values for columns A-H
rows = [97, 165, 235] # give 12 values for rows 1-12
#...
for row = 0 to 3:
    for column = 0 to 7:
        center_column = columns[column]
        center_row = rows[row]
        #... get img pixels and process b,g,r values
```

Comment: So in particular you never got `center[0]>360` because it was a colour value 0..255.

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I would rewrite your code:

```
import cv2
from itertools import product
import numpy as np
import sys

# image coordinates
ROWS = (891, 820, 750, 680, 607, 537, 466, 396, 324, 254, 184, 110)   # rows 1..12
COLS = (582, 511, 442, 373, 305, 235, 165, 97)                        # cols A..H

def get_rect_avg_color(img, x, y, w=8, h=8):
    """
    Return the BGR average color of a rectangular area of the image
      centered on (x,y) with width w and height h
    """
    half_w = w // 2
    half_h = h // 2
    # extract the rectangular area
    rect = img[x - half_w: x + (w - half_w) + 1, y - half_h: y + (h - half_h) + 1]
    # average each channel independantly
    avg_col = rect.mean(axis=(0,1))
    return avg_col    # returns [avg_b, avg_g, avg_r]

def get_cells_avg_color(img, cells):
    """
    Return the BGR average color of a list of cells
    """
    cell_colors = np.vstack(get_rect_avg_color(img, *cell) for cell in cells)
    return cell_colors.mean(axis=0)    # returns [avg_b, avg_g, avg_r]

def get_cells(col_from, col_to, row_from, row_to):
    """
    Return a list of all cells in a rectangular block

    col_from, col_to  in "A".."H"
    row_from, row_to  in 1..12

    col_to and row_to are inclusive
    """
    col_from  = ord(col_from.upper()) - ord("A")
    col_to    = ord(col_to  .upper()) - ord("A")
    col_from, col_to = min(col_from, col_to), max(col_from, col_to)
    row_from -= 1
    row_to   -= 1
    row_from, row_to = min(row_from, row_to), max(row_from, row_to)
    return product(ROWS[row_from:row_to + 1], COLS[col_from:col_to + 1])

def main(img_fname):
    img = cv2.imread(img_fname)

    first_cells = get_cells("A", "G", 9, 12)
    first_avg = get_cells_avg_color(img, first_cells)
    print("First color average: blue {:0.2f}, green {:0.2f}, red {:0.2f}".format(*first_avg))

    second_cells = get_cells("A", "G", 5, 8)
    second_avg = get_cells_avg_color(img, second_cells)
    print("Second color average: blue {:0.2f}, green {:0.2f}, red {:0.2f}".format(*second_avg))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    if len(sys.argv) == 2:
        main(sys.argv[1])
    else:
        print("Usage: python {} plate.jpg".format(__name__))
```

Comment: More effort than I put in :)